# Обращение к объекту из ArrayList по его полям

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

Уважаемые сэнсэи, гуру и мастера Йоды Java, нужна подмога. Ситуация тривиальная, но тревожащая мой покой. Возможно ли в Java обратиться к элементу `ArrayList` типа `Object` по какому-то из его полей? В идеале мы вводим с клавиатуры строку "*January*" сравниваем её с полем объекта **jan** через foreach (я полагаю) и что-то тогда уже выводим. А в идеале было бы чудно, если бы можно было проверить есть ли поле *January* хоть у какого-то объекта в `ArrayList` :)

```
public class Test{
String monText;
int monChislo;
public Test(String monText, int monChislo){
   this.monText = monText;
   this.monChislo = monChislo;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Test jan = new Test("January", 1);
   Test feb = new Test ("February", 2);
   Test mar = new Test ("March", 3);
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(jan);
   list.add(feb );
   list.add(mar );
String month = reader.readLine();
   for (Object obj: list) {
      if (что сюда написать?)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` - это суперкласс для всех классов, поэтому он может содержать любой тип. Если тип объектов известен, то можно кастить в рантайме к нужному типу, и тогда уже использовать его поля. Просто надо различать тип объекта при компиляции может отличаться от типа в рантайме.

Поскольку все объекты имеют известный тип, то нет необходимости кастить к нужному типу, вместо этого нужно использовать тип параметра объекта `ArrayList`.

```
   Test jan = new Test("January", 1);
   Test feb = new Test ("February", 2);
   Test mar = new Test ("March", 3);
   ArrayList<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(jan);
   list.add(feb );
   list.add(mar );
   String month = reader.readLine();
   for (Test obj: list) {
      if (obj.monText...)
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. Придётся привести `obj` к типу имеющему нужные поля.

```
for (Object obj: list) {
  String month = ((Test) obj).monText;
  if ("January".equals(month))
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста эту строку - ((Test) obj).monText;

Comment: @Makaroni приведение `obj` к `Test` и присваивание переменной `month` значение поля `monText`.

Comment: Большое спасибо)