# ArrayList к Integer. Приведение типов

Tags: java

java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

```
       static Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer> > hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public static void main(String... arg) {
     printValues();
    }
    private static void printValues() {
      // Add data with duplicate keys
      ArrayList<Integer> f=new ArrayList<Integer>();

      f.add(2);f.add(7);

       addValues(1, f);
       addValues(1, f);
       addValues(2, f);
       // View data.
       Iterator<Integer> it = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
       ArrayList<Integer>  tempList = null;

       while (it.hasNext()) {
          Integer key = it.next();             
          tempList = hashMap.get(key);
          if (tempList != null) {
//ошибка в этой строке---->
             for (Integer value: tempList) {
                System.out.println("Key : "+key+ " , Value : "+value);
             }
          }
       }
    }


    private static void addValues(Integer key, ArrayList<Integer> value) {
       ArrayList tempList = null;
       if (hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
          tempList = hashMap.get(key);
          if(tempList == null)
             tempList = new ArrayList();
          tempList.add(value);  
       } else {
          tempList = new ArrayList();
          tempList.add(value);               
       }
       hashMap.put(key,tempList);
    }
```

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/958119/204920

Answer (score 1):

```
tempList.add(value);
```

`tempList` имеет тип `ArrayList<Integer>`, то есть это `ArrayList`, который хранит внутри себя `Integer`. Вы пытаетесь записать в него `value` - `ArrayList<Integer>`. Т.е. внутрь `ArrayList` хотите вставить другой `ArrayList`, вот и вываливается ошибка. Вам нужно записывать внутрь не `ArrayList`, а значения из него:

```
tempList.addAll(value);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Исправил опечатку в коде.